# JTAG: How do I know the width of the Instruction Register?

Tags: jtag

Assumed I have a JTAG-chain with several devices from different manufactures:
How does my software, which shall communicate with a specific system within that chain, known the length of the IR for all the others devices within the chain? I do have to know them to send a certain instruction to my device, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to detect the total length of all IR registers in your JTAG daisy-chain. It is also possible to detect the number of devices (or TAPs) in your chain. But you can't detect the individual IR length of a single TAP.

What you can do: You can read out the JTAG ID code register of all of you TAPs. The ID code register (in DR path) is always 32 bit and gets selected by test-logic-reset.

With the ID code you can identify the existing TAPs and look up in the datasheet the length of the individual IR registers.

And yes: In general you do have to know the individual IR length of all the TAPs in your chain to communicate with one of them.

Comment: Isn't the ID-register optional? How could I work with such devices? Also, how could I connect several devices from different manufacturers to a single JTAG chain? I suppose that the manufacturers don't know the length of each other device?

Comment: Yes, the ID register is optional, but rather common. If more than one of your devices does not have an ID register then the mentioned approach will not work. JTAG compliant devices of several vendors can be put in a daisy chain. Reading out the IR length of a single device can be done by shifting a known pattern through the IR register. So unless a JTAG port is not locked by some magic mechanism, everybody can read the IR length of any device.

Comment: When entering Test-Logic-Reset, then the ID register is selected if supported, which is always 32 bit long and has LSB value of 1, and if ID register is not supported, then mandatory Bypass register is selected, which is always 1 bit long and has (LSB) value of 0.    Since LSB is shifted out first, it is thereby possible to determine the number of devices in the scan chain, knowing that a LSB of 0 indicates a 1 bit Bypass register, and a LSB of 1 indicates a 32 bit ID register.

Answer (score 0):

try here: http://www.fpga4fun.com/JTAG3.html
When IR = '1...1', the BYPASS is selected. 
The idea is to send a lot of '1' so regardless of IR length all devices will select BYPASS.